# How can I convert between a List of boxed primitives to their unboxed counterparts in java using a generic method?

Tags: java, generics, primitive-types

Say I have some lists:

```
List<Short> shortList;
List<Integer> integerList;
List<Long> longList;
List<Float> floatList;
List<Double> doubleList;
List<Boolean> booleanList;
```

And I want to convert them into their primitive equivalent:

```
short[] shortArray;
int[] intArray;
long[] longArray;
float[] floatArray;
double[] doubleArray;
boolean[] booleanArray;
```

I want to make a method to that accepts any type of `List` of boxed primitives and return the equivalent array of unboxed primitives. I am not up to speed at Generics, so I took a shot and it doesn't work. This is what I have:

```
public static E[] convertObjectListToPrimitiveArray(List<T> list)
{
    E[] primitiveArray = new E[list.size()];
    int i=0;
    for(T object : list){
        E[i++] = object;
    }
    return primitiveArray;
}
```

What do I need to do to make this method work?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Very nice catch -- an exact match of OP's task! It's odd that it is not very popular - in four and a half years it got only a thousand hits or so. I'd expect the view count to be much higher.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Agreed ... I did, what I would call, a thorough search through Google and never found that post.

Comment: Having duplicates like this helps build search presence, so it's all good.